# basic_string::_S_construct null not valid - can't figure out why?

Tags: c++, string, null

I am converting some code so to stop using char*, and use std::string instead for avoiding memory leaks and/or buffer overloads.

But I have come to a function where I get the above error. I haven't really changed much atm:

```
GuiText::GuiText(std::string t, int s, XeColor c) {
origText = NULL;
text = NULL;
size = s;
color = c;
alpha = c.a;
style = FTGX_JUSTIFY_CENTER | FTGX_ALIGN_MIDDLE;
maxWidth = 0;
wrap = false;
textDynNum = 0;
textScroll = SCROLL_NONE;
textScrollPos = 0;
textScrollInitialDelay = TEXT_SCROLL_INITIAL_DELAY;
textScrollDelay = TEXT_SCROLL_DELAY;

alignmentHor = ALIGN_CENTRE;
alignmentVert = ALIGN_MIDDLE;

if (!t.empty()) {
    origText = strdup(t.c_str());
    text = charToWideChar(gettext(t.c_str()));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    textDyn[i] = NULL;
}
```

All of the code is here https://github.com/siz-/xmplayer/blob/temp/source/libwiigui/gui_text.cpp#L32

All was daisy becasue I have numerous instances of GuiText, but when I comment the function using const char* on line 59 and in gui.h to actually make my code use the correct function, i get the above error.. I can't see why..

https://github.com/siz-/xmplayer/blob/temp/source/libwiigui/gui_text.cpp#L59
https://github.com/siz-/xmplayer/blob/temp/source/libwiigui/gui.h#L685

Example of how it's used: 
https://github.com/siz-/xmplayer/blob/temp/source/menu.cpp#L427

Any ideas? I have already converted all of gui_text.cpp, but same error, so better to try to pinpoint the problem and get going from there.

Hope you can help a newb ;-)

Comment: You can't initialize a `std::string` with a null pointer.

Comment: so I have to set t? but don't I do that when I am using the function?  or should I add a if(t.empty()) { t = ""; }?

Comment: You can't pass a null pointer into the function. It's too late inside the function.

Comment: so I have to check if it's null before I use the function?

Comment: Yes, or avoid it being null in the first place (e.g., using a `std::string` from the get-go).

Comment: in the example I link to, there shouldn't be NULL, or is it because I am missing a & ?

Comment: By the way, `(XeColor){...}` isn't standard C++. Anyway, it would be really helpful if you could narrow down the problem without us having to wade through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. It's because in menu.cpp where the example, it's starts by setting some of the Guitext = NULL.. Thanks for the help, it clarified me about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Somewhere, you are doing something like `GuiText text(NULL, ...);`. This used to call `GuiText(const char*, ...)` overload, which checks for the pointer being NULL. But now that you've removed this overload, the same code calls `GuiText(string(NULL), ...)`. It is `string(NULL)` part that fails: the execution never enters `GuiText` constructor at all, so nothing you do in the constructor can possibly help. You have to fix the calling code to not pass `NULL` in the first place. Your debugger should make it easy to find the offending code.

Comment: Well I am using libxenon for xbox 360 (legal homebrewing) that doesn't have a debugger.. Atm I think the culprits are something like: https://github.com/siz-/xmplayer/blob/temp/source/menu.cpp#L153 <-- but if I change NULL to "" or some text it doesn't find them, so I think it's setting the GuiText element to NULL and not it's GuiText constructor..

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the following 2 lines are attempting to initialize a string:

```
origText = NULL;
text = NULL;
```

Which should 1) be initialized in an initializer list and 2) if it is going to be empty, is not needed, and 3) is not valid (you cannot initialize a string to `NULL`).

```
GuiText::GuiText(std::string t, int s, XeColor c) :
    origText(t),
    size(s),
    color(c),
    alpha(c.a),
    style(FTGX_JUSTIFY_CENTER | FTGX_ALIGN_MIDDLE),
    // etc
{
    // etc
}
```

Comment: origText is const char *, and text is wchar_t* (from gui.h).

Comment: `const char` or `const char*`?  In either case, that will introduce you to another bug later.  If you are calling the constructor with `NULL` instead of `""`, you will also get that error.

Comment: @siz I guess you meant `const char*` and `wchar_t*` respectively, otherwise you should not set them to `NULL` (and for pointers, you should use `nullptr`)

Comment: yes i did :) using * without minimarking apparently makes the text italic? :D